# Cypress unable to find the configuration file

Tags: cypress

I am not able to figured it out what went wrong, when i ran the command **npm run test:qa**  it says Could not find the Cypress configuration file.

//package.json
{
"name": "cypress-testautomation",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "This is a practice ",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test:qa": "cypress run --config-file cypress.qa.json",
"test:uat": "cypress run --config-file cypress.uat.json",
"test:production": "cypress run --config-file cypress.production.json",
"cypress:open": "cypress open",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
"author": "XXXXXXXXX",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"cypress": "^13.2.0"
}
}

```
// cypress.qa.json
{
  "baseUrl": "https://ui.cogmento.com/",
  "email": "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
  "password": "XXXXXXX"
} 

//commands.js 
Cypress.Commands.add('loadEnvironmentConfig', (env) => {
    return cy.readFile(`cypress.${env}.json`).then((config) => {
        Cypress.config('env', config);
    });
});

// cypress/e2e/vibe/mytest.cy.js
describe('Environment-Specific Test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // Load QA environment config
        cy.loadEnvironmentConfig('qa');
    });

    it('Visits the specified environment', () => {
        const baseUrl = Cypress.config('env').baseUrl; // Access environment-specific data

        cy.visit(baseUrl); // Visit the specified URL
        cy.title().should('have', 'Cogmento CRM')
        cy.get('input[name = "email"]').type(Cypress.config('env').email); // Use email id
        cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(Cypress.config('env').password); // Use password
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
        cy.title().should('have', 'CRMPRO')

        // Perform other test actions using environment-specific data
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a muddle up of different versions in your project.

Cypress **v9** uses `*.json` files and you have yours in the `/cypress` folder.

Therefore, you would add the `/cypress` folder into the path in the CLI script, like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test:qa": "cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.qa.json"
  ...
```

But you also have Cypress **v10+** configuration `cypress.config.js` which is also in the Cypress folder, so maybe you need to convert `cypress.qa.json` to `cypress.config.qa.json`.

Finally, you should park those files in the project root folder.

If you don't understand, take some time to read this documentation page [Cypress configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration). All the information you need is there.

Comment: No all the json files are @Project level (look at the 3rd screenshot below the error screenshot) not in the Cypress folder

Comment: The indent on the picture tells a different story. If you close the cypress folder are they still listed?

Comment: Yes! To make it clear i have added clean picture (3rd screenshot)

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't clarified it.